# Xamarin Visual Studio не обновляет приложение на android emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, эмулятор

Xamarin Visual Studio не обновляет приложение на android emulator.
Запускаю дебаг для андроида.

Происходит билд и деплой. Но пока эмулятор на андроиде стартует - студия уже выкидывает из дебага и задеплоить не может.

Как полечить? 
Если эмулятор не закрывать и жать дебаг то приложение деплоится нормально и студия заходит в дебаг.

При этом после запуска VS и первого дебага проект деплоится нормально. А повторные дебаги не проходят. Приложение не обновляется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но пока эмулятор на андроиде стартует - студия уже выкидывает из дебага и 
>   задеплоить не может.

лечил рестартом эмулятора.

> При этом после запуска VS и первого дебага проект деплоится нормально.
>   А повторные дебаги не проходят. Приложение не обновляется.

мне помогало удаление приложения с эмулятора.